# How do I disable the alt-right click keyboard binding?

Tags: unity, compiz, keyboard

Using Oneiric 11.10 and Unity. I want to disable the context menu that appears with Alt+RightClick. Alt+RightClick is a much used shortcut in Blender. It's possible to remap keys in Blender, but I was hoping to be able to turn it off in Ubuntu so that Blender get scontrol. I update my Blender installation often, so it's more convenient not to have to change settings every time.

Answer (score 22):

It's in CCSM ▸ General ▸ General options ▸ Key bindings ▸ "Window Menu" ( <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Button3)

Because disabling it does not work (at least in 12.04 and 12.10, probably earlier versions too), you will need to change the shortcut to something else, like <kbd>Super</kbd> + Button3.

[image]

**Warning - You should be very careful when using `ccsm`; see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) for details.**

Comment: The answer seems correct, but disabling the `Window menu` didn't have any effect for me. The menu still pops up in Blender. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Just for the record, the contents of this answer also apply to Linux Mint 18 running with "Compiz"..

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem and it's happened to me twice now. Both times I found this post and tried the suggestion of disabling the key binding and it does not work. However **changing** does work. I changed mine to shift-alt-rmb and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [site](http://ubuntuguide.net/disable-alt-click-moving-windows-ubuntu-12-04), overall:

1. Install dconf-tools using `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Launch the app
3. Navigate org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> preferences.
4. Set value of **mouse-button-modifier** to: none will disable Alt + left/right/middle key at next login OR switch to other keys, such as `<Ctrl>`, `<Super>`, etc.

Hopefully this will help you out.

Comment: Ugh., that created a mess here. For those with similar problem, just restore the defaults:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Alt>'

Comment: well, he asked to disable the '<Alt>' key and i gave solution to disable it OR to change it with other key and of course using the same method to restore Alt key function is possible.

Comment: Changing `<Alt>` to `none` has the effect of treating left mouse click and drag as move window and right mouse click shows window menu. But entering `<Super>` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,
there is a bug in ubuntu / unity related to hardcoded shortcuts. Thats why changing the shortcuts in settings does nothing.

For anyone who is searching solution for this problem - i think there is none for now (other than changing it in the ubuntu / unity code). You can only change the shortcut in blender, or you can use in blender shift+alt+rmb instead of alt+rmb, which is generally the same, but stands for add loop to selection (with shift), not select loop.

You can check the details about the ubunut bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1022743

Answer (score 0):

There is bug and it can be disabled. Instead we need to assign it to some less or not used shortcut. So i used Crtl+Shift+Alt+Button2(middle button of mouse). There is no other option than mouse buttons to use. Though there are up to 20 button options, choosing button20 dummy will reset it to button3 or any of the button you set before.

**Brief** use `Crtl+Shift+Alt+Button2` as shortcut

Note: And you need CCSM to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be changed but you need to use CCSM -> general settings. Any other attept to disable/ change it failed. Hope someone will fix this soon. thnx for your time.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using linux mint 20 and it's easy to solve the problem of window move and resize by clicking the alt or ctrl key and right click problem...

just go to
system Setting-> Preferences->Windows->Behavior-> Disable the Special Key to move and Resize Windows.

Comment: Since Linux Mint is off-topic here, answering using Mint as an example may not be useful.