# Turn off shift right click to change workspaces

Tags: shortcut-keys

How do I turn off the workspace menu when doing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+RIGHT CLICK? I am trying to learn blender and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+RIGHT CLICK is used in blender for selecting multiple objects. This is also a problem with certain games.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I disable the alt-right click keyboard binding?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70392/how-do-i-disable-the-alt-right-click-keyboard-binding) Has the answer. I had forgot that  had changed the settings once before. Thanks for viewing.