# Disable alt+rightclick in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz, blender

I'd like to disable the alt+rightclik keybinding as it is shared by Blender. All of the [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70392/how-do-i-disable-the-alt-right-click-keyboard-binding) so far have involved using ccsm, but so far, that hasn't worked for me. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)**  Could you try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier ''` and report back?

Comment: Thanks. That command completely messed up my mouse bindings though - I'm having to shift+leftclick for normal click. Leftclick turned into drag, and rightclick turned into window menu. How do I set it back please?

Comment: OK, with a bit of research, I found this command, which returned everything to normal: `gsettingsreset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier`

Comment: Only back on-line now.  '<alt>' was the original modifier.  Setting it to anything other then that has worked as I can see!

Comment: I used this method on ubuntu 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/a/521447/667618  to disable alt+rmb, because I would like to use in within blender to select edge loops!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of research following Fabby's comment - I used the following command, which has worked:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Super>'`

Now it's the super key which brings up the window menu.

Comment: Thank you for your research. I did this and it worked for me as well, where Compiz could not change any Ubuntu 16 keybindings for some reason.